# Can I see WP blog in SHP Online?

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint-online

I want to see Wordpress blog (from already existing wordpress page) to my new SharePoint site. Is it possible? If so, what should I obtain to make it work?

It would be best to see it for example as newsfeed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can use the default WordPress RSS feed of your Blog (example.com) at the address URL:

```
https://example.com/feed/
```

Then on your SharePoint Site you will have to Add and configure the RSS Viewer Web Part as described on the Step 2 of the official documentation.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-rss-feeds-from-external-sites-to-your-site-52c26fb9-f1e7-44b7-b684-dea7b5788590

> If so, what should I obtain to make it work?

You will gain content on your SharePoint Site with possible links to your WordPress blog.

Comment: I see this guide is for SharePoint classic. It means its not possible for SharePoint Online?

Comment: Yep it is not clear under the main heading it's said **SharePoint Online SharePoint Server 2016 SharePoint Foundation 2013 More...** and a few lines below **Important: For SharePoint Online, the RSS Viewer Web Part is available only in classic SharePoint.** Do you have access to classic SharePoint?